# best way to add comments in HTML Closing tag with VIM

Tags: html, vim, comments

I'm learning to use VIM and I like it.

But in many case of long content tag I usually add comments after the HTML closing tag, normally using the name of class attribute as a comment for example ...

```
<div class="product-list">

  product contents inside

</div> <!-- product-list -->
```

My question is how can I add the comment `<!-- product-list -->` in VIM

What I can do so far is type `product-list` and then `v ^` to select the whole word, I feel that I'm close to make it possible but I did not find way to continue to complete it with `<!--` and `-->`

So what I did currently is just type every single charecters  which kind of annoying.

Any advise please?

Comment: What does `v ^` do ?

Comment: opps, I means `v i W` to select the whole word from last cursor position back to beginning character of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing html the normal way is tedious. Instead, use the [emmet style](http://emmet.io/);

> Emmet is a plugin for many popular text editors which greatly improves
>   HTML & CSS workflow.

It's vim plugin is [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim);

> emmet-vim is a vim plug-in which provides support for expanding
>   abbreviations similar to emmet.

You can achieve your desired behaviour using [`c` filter](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/e5d28f004ccc6f0cdd3e100b985ee30333b4ed83/doc/emmet.txt#L1636-L1689):

```
.product-list|c
```

will expand to:

```
<!-- .product-list -->
<div class="product-list">|</div>
<!-- /.product-list -->
```

To insert only the second comment add to your `.vimrc`:

```
  let g:user_emmet_settings = {
  \    'html' : {
  \        'comment_type': 'lastonly'
  \    }
  \}
```

Then:

```
.product-list|c
```

will expand to:

```
<div class="product-list">|</div><!-- .product-list -->
```

(`|` is the cursor position after expansion.)

Comment: wow! I actually use emmet-vim but didn't realize that I can use it with `|c`. This is what exactly I'm looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've tried this and also the ``'<C-y>/'`` key combo for creating comments and it's not working. Is there an additional step that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a mapping that can help you to save some keystrokes:

```
:inoremap <! <!-- product-list --><Esc>gEviW
```

Whenever you type <kbd>**<**</kbd><kbd>**!**</kbd> during insert-mode it will insert directly `<!-- product-list -->` and do a selection for you.

Comment: Thank you. This is really help. For my case, I will need only `:inoremap <! <!-- --><Esc>gEa`

Answer (score 1):

You could save this macro in your `vimrc`:

```
:let @e = '$h%/\(id\|class\)^Myi"%A <!-- ^R" -->^[:nohl^M'
```

and use it with `@e` with the cursor on the closing tag.

Use `<C-v><CR>` to insert `^M`, `<C-v><C-r>` to insert `^R`, and `<C-v><Esc>` to insert `^[`.

Comment: You did not mention that this answer works only if you have already added `matchit` plugin package in your vim . See `:help matchit-install`

Answer (score 1):

I did use [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) plugin, heres the code:

```
snippet tcom "generic html tag with coment" w
<${1:div}>
 ${2:content}
</${1/(\w+).*/$1/}> <!-- ${1/.*="([^"]+)".*/$1/} -->
${0}
endsnippet
```

Explanation about the comment:

```
$1 ............... mirror placeholder one
/ ................ start substitution on it
.*=" ............. anything until the first "
( ................ start a group match
[^"]+ ............ inside quotes
" ................ closing "
.* ............... the rest of the line
```

We are using only what we have between ", like "this-string"